# Find DNF and CNF for the formulas

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Find DNF for the formula. (I've reserched some information. So do I must firstly to find PDNF, like (x ̅ ¯y  ¯z ⋀ x ̅ ¯yz ⋀ x ̅yz ⋀ x¯y  ¯z ⋀ xyz)  or ..?)
f (x, y,z) =  (11011001)

> Find CNF for the formula:
>   $$((x|y)↓ \overline{z}))→(x+y\overline{z})$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: It's a little hard to read, do you mean find CNF of   $((x|y)↓ \overline{z}))→(x+y\overline{z})?$